# Как можно принудительно сохранить ui файл? Выходит ошибка This file contains top level spacers

Tags: qt, pyqt5, qt-designer, pyside2

Как можно принудительно сохранить ui файл?
Просто не могу найти где нехватает layout (по-моему везде все стоит)

Может ли данная ошибка выходить из-за большого количества layout?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: начните с начала. Кинули пару виджетов и сохранили и т.д. На каком-то этапе  поймаете сообщение и подумаете что не так.

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html#setting-a-top-level-layout